# Make a numpy upper triangular matrix padded with Nan instead of zero

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I generate a matplotlib 3d surface plot.  I only need to see the upper-triangular half of the matrix on the plot, as the other half is redundant.

np.triu() makes the redundant half of the matrix zeros, but I'd prefer if I can make them Nans, then those cells don't show up at all on the surface plot.

What would be a pythonic way to fill with NaN instead of zeros?  I cannot do a search-and-replace 0 with NaN, as zeros will appear in the legitimate data I want to display.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `numpy.tril_indices()` to assign the `NaN` value to lower triangle, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.triu(np.arange(0, 12, dtype=np.float).reshape(4,3))
>>> m
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  8.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> m[np.tril_indices(m.shape[0], -1)] = np.nan
>>> m
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [ nan,   4.,   5.],
       [ nan,  nan,   8.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, I like it.

Answer (score 6):

[`tril_indices()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) might be the obvious approach here that generates the lower triangular indices and then you can use those to set those in input array to `NaNs`.

Now, if you care about performance, you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) after creating a mask of such lower triangular shape and then set those to `NaNs`. The implementation would look like this -

```
m[np.arange(m.shape[0])[:,None] > np.arange(m.shape[1])] = np.nan
```

So, `np.arange(m.shape[0])[:,None] > np.arange(m.shape[1])` is the mask here that was created using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Sample run -

```
In [51]: m
Out[51]: 
array([[ 11.,  49.,  23.,  30.],
       [ 40.,  41.,  19.,  26.],
       [ 32.,  36.,  30.,  25.],
       [ 15.,  27.,  25.,  40.],
       [ 33.,  18.,  45.,  43.]])

In [52]: np.arange(m.shape[0])[:,None] > np.arange(m.shape[1]) # mask
Out[52]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [53]: m[np.arange(m.shape[0])[:,None] > np.arange(m.shape[1])] = np.nan

In [54]: m
Out[54]: 
array([[ 11.,  49.,  23.,  30.],
       [ nan,  41.,  19.,  26.],
       [ nan,  nan,  30.,  25.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  40.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Runtime tests -

This section compares the boolean indexing based approach listed in this solution to `np.tril_indices` based one in the [`other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33029411/3293881) for performance.

```
In [38]: m = np.random.randint(10,50,(1000,1100)).astype(float)

In [39]: %timeit m[np.tril_indices(m.shape[0], -1)] = np.nan
10 loops, best of 3: 62.8 ms per loop

In [40]: m = np.random.randint(10,50,(1000,1100)).astype(float)

In [41]: %timeit m[np.arange(m.shape[0])[:,None] > np.arange(m.shape[1])] = np.nan
100 loops, best of 3: 8.03 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ha, pretty slick solution.  Fortunately my matrix is small, but for a giant matrix, makes good sense.

Answer (score -1):

Shape or layout doesn't matter for the purpose of this example, so let's say we have a 2D array a such that:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

and we want all 0 values to be NaN.  Just use a list comprehension.

```
>>> b = numpy.array([[i if i else numpy.nan for i in j] for j in a])
>>> b
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.]])
```

If you have specific cells that won't be zero, then specify them in the comprehension.

Comment: Thanks.  Dunno, so far everything I've encountered with numpy is, "if its doing iterations, you're not doing it ideally".  I suspect there will be more pythonic answers to this problem.